# Relations of a Spherical Triangle using Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

I've been trying to study the spherical triangle using Differential Geometry. My goal is to find relations between the area, the perimeter and the internal angles of the triangle. But I've got stuck in my formulas. I'll expose now my thoughts:

Let $\psi(\theta, \phi) = (rcos(\theta)sen(\phi), rsen(\theta)sen(\phi), rcos(\phi)), (\theta,\phi) \in U = (0,2\pi) \times (0,\pi).$

On this parametrization, we have the following metric: $ g = \begin{bmatrix} r^{2}sen^{2}(\phi)&0 \\ 0&r^{2} \end{bmatrix}$.

Let $q_{i} = (\theta_{i},\phi_{i}) \in U, i =1,2,3, p_{i} = \psi(q_{i})$.

I set $\gamma_{i}^{j}:I_{i}^{j}=(a_{i}^{j},b_{i}^{j}) \rightarrow U$ such that $\gamma_{i}^{j}(a_{i}^{j})=q_{i}$, $\gamma_{i}^{j}(b_{i}^{j})=q_{j}$. And also supposed that $|\gamma_{i}^{j \; \prime}(s)| = 1, \forall s \in I_{i}^{j}$.

Then, $\gamma_{i}^{j}(s) = (\theta_{i}^{j}(s),\phi_{i}^{j}(s)) \Rightarrow \theta_{i}^{j \; \prime 2}(s) + \phi_{i}^{j \; \prime 2}(s) = 1, \forall s \in I_{i}^{j}$.

With this definitions, we have that $\psi \circ \alpha_{i}^{j}(I_{i}^{j}), (i,j) = (1,2), (2,3), (3,1)$ define a spherical triangle.

I computed now the length of the sides of the triangle:
$$l_{i}^{j} = l ( \psi \circ \alpha_{i}^{j}) = \int\limits_{a_{i}^{j}}^{b_{i}^{j}} r^{2} \left( (\theta_{i}^{j \prime}(s))^{2} sen(\phi_{i}^{j}(s)) + (\phi_{i}^{j \prime}(s))^{2} \right) ds$$.

From my definitions, it is obvious that the perimeter P is given by $P = l_{1}^{2} + l_{2}^{3} + l_{3}^{1}$.

I also computed the angles $\alpha_{i}, i=1,2,3$ that the curves $\psi \circ \alpha_{i}^{j}$ make on the each point $p_{i}$. And I found:

$$cos (\alpha_{i}) =  \frac{\theta_{i}^{j \; \prime}(0)\theta_{i}^{k \; \prime}(0) sen(\theta_{i}) + \phi_{i}^{j \; \prime}(0) \phi_{i}^{k \; \prime}(0)}{\phi_{i}^{j \; \prime}(0)\phi_{i}^{j \; \prime}(0)sen^{2}(\phi_{i}) + (\theta_{i}^{j \; \prime}(0)\phi_{i}^{k \; \prime}(0) + \theta_{i}^{k \; \prime}(0)\phi_{i}^{j \; \prime}(0))sen(\phi_{i}) + \phi_{i}^{j \; \prime}(0)\phi_{i}^{k \; \prime}(0)},$$

for $(i,j,k) = (1,2,3), (2,3,1), (3,1,2)$.

At last, we have that the area of the spherical triangle is given by

$$ A = \iint\limits_{Q} \sqrt{det(g)} d\theta d\phi = \iint\limits_{Q} r^{2} sen (\phi) d\theta d\phi,$$

where $Q \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is the region bounded by the three curves $\alpha_{i}^{j}, (i,j)=(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)$.

The problem is that I don't know how to proceed with my calculations. I've been using generic curves $\alpha_{i}^{j}$ and seems to me it is impossible to characterize the region Q. I tried to use Stokes' Theorem using a vector field $\vec{F}: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ ($S=$sphere) such that $\nabla \times \vec{F} = N$, where N is the Gauss map, which is unitary and normal everywhere on the sphere. With this, $(\nabla \times \vec{F}) \cdot \hat{n} = 1 \Rightarrow \iint dA = \oint \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}$. However, I noticed that such a vector field does not exist, since $div(N) = \frac{3}{r} \neq 0$.

What can I do now?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem#For_triangles

Comment: There's a huge flaw here. Nowhere have you stipulated that the edges of the triangle are “straight,” i.e., arcs of grrat circles.